# Collector current in datasheet Graphs

Tags: power-electronics, current-measurement, semiconductors, igbt, power-modules

Here is an example of output characteristics fot IGBT devices, i.e., the "collector current (Ic)-to-collector emitter voltage (Vce)" graph. Can somebody help me find what Ic represents here? I mean, is Ic the average, rms, or something else?
If it is DC current, so what can Ic represent in "Ic-to-switching energy loss (Esw)" graph?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *Can somebody help me find what Ic represents here? I mean, is Ic the
> average, rms, or something else?*

It's a DC current if you want it to be or, it's a peak current if the applied voltage (\$V_{CE}\$) is pulsed. It compares collector current against an x-axis of collector-emitter voltage so, whatever waveform is used for one is used for the other.